# iframe span page width

Tags: html, iframe

I would like my `iframe` to span the width of the page, and go down to the bottom of the page. In [this w3 page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) I see the width and height options, but they must be specified in pixels. How can I set it to span the way I would like?

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/EAbnX/1/

Comment: The height and width attributes can be expressed in %, em, and other measures, not just px (if placed in CSS that is).

Comment: Solution by stealthyninja is perfect for 100% situations. If you want some other kind of implementation, then you need javascript and bind (jquery)  the document.ready and window.resize events to do your calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code that will be display what u want but if you don't want to use px...

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="180px" height="180px">
```

than you can use % for specifies the height and width of frame... it will take an percentage of main frame size which is 1080px..

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="30%" height="20%">
```